# Relink access table

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

‎‎I have a split access database that contains a lot of tables, all tables would relink correctly, except for one table. That table gives me an error when specifying the new location. the err says that it can't find that old path.

Why is it looking for the old path? I'm specifying a new path!

If I delete the table and relink it, it would add it, but I wont be able to open it. the error message is the same, although in the link table manager it displays the correct path (not the one in the error)

The only workaround I found working is to make a copy of the table in the database file, delete the table there, rename the copy file to original name.

But that only helps until I need to relink it again. and its a long process.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try the function I use when I need to manually set the table path.

```
Function SetTableLinkPath(strTableName As String, strTablePath As String)
On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    If Nz(strTableName, "") <> "" And Nz(strTablePath, "") <> "" Then
        Dim cdb As DAO.Database

        Set cdb = CurrentDb

        cdb.TableDefs(strTableName).Connect = ";DATABASE=" & strTablePath
        cdb.TableDefs(strTableName).RefreshLink

        MsgBox "Table link for " & strTableName & " has been successfully set to the path: " & strTablePath & "."
    Else
        MsgBox "You must enter a valid Table path and name!"
    End If


Exit_Handler:
    Set cdb = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    'Your error handling
Resume Exit_Handler
End Function
```

Comment: Same problem with that table.